# Generate random latitude and longitude with javascript after geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

Is it possible with javascript to generate random latitude and longitude based on the user current position? I want to generate some random latitude and longitude positions after that the user is geolocated to place some markers on a leaflet map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, Code below:

```
var latBounds = [-122, -77];
  var lngBounds = [30, 50];
  
var features = [];

  for( var i=0; i<80000; i++ ){
    var lat = Math.random() * (latBounds[1]- latBounds[0] + 1) + latBounds[0];
    var lng = Math.random() * (lngBounds[1]- lngBounds[0] + 1) + lngBounds[0];
    features.push({
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [lat, lng]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "point_" +i,
        "marker-symbol": "harbor"
      }
    });
  }
  var geoJSON = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": features
  };
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. So the best approach is to use geoJSON right? Just one question, why you've used this value `80000` to increment the count?

Comment: Yes u can create a geojson it will work for your case and 80000 is just dummy number, edit it as per your need. Hope it helps!

Comment: the latitude and longitude bounds are provided by the user geolocated position right?

Comment: I believe as per your case you can get that from user current location

Comment: Tested the code, the geoJSON array is filled correctly, but Leaflet will not display the desired markers on the map :(

Comment: Can you please elaborate  "Leaflet will not display the desired markers on the map "? I didn't get your point.

Comment: Ok, sorry. So I have followed your suggestion to create random coordinates and I have created an array that is passed to the `L.geoJSON` function of leaflet. After that the map is loaded and the user geolocated I will fill the array using the code you've suggested. What I expect is to see markers appear on the map, what is happen is that no markers is displayed on the map. see this question I've posted for the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956741/leaflet-geojson-data-not-add-markers-on-displayed-map)